# Cambiar columna que verifica la contraseña en Auth::attemp() Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una tabla User:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('document');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->foreignIdFor(City::class);
            $table->string('password_user');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Pero cuando uso:

```
Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password_user' => $data['password_user'],
]);
```

Me tira que la contraseña no es correcta, y no puedo loguearme

Creo que el problema es que Auth::attempt() toma la contraseña de la columna 'password' pero esa columna no existe y me tira error, no se si se pueda cambiar la columna de 'password' que utiliza Auth::attemp() por otra columna.

Gracias

Comment: que dice la documentacion???

Comment: Hola @FranciscoNuñezIALover En la documentación comenta que se puede cambiar el 'email' por 'username', pero no como cambiar la password pero en ningun momento comenta como cambiar la columna 'password'

Comment: debe ser _Auth::attempt_ en lugar de _Auth::attemp_

Comment: pero tu no estas cambiando estas autenticando primero ...

Comment: Ya realize la edición y le añadi la 't'

Comment: Lo que dice la documentación es que se puede cambiar la columna 'email' por cualquier otra por ejemplo 'username' o 'user', pero no como cambiar la columna que revisa la contraseña

Comment: y si cambias: _'password_user' => $data['password_user']_ , por _'password' => $data['password_user']_

Comment: motivo por el cual no me gustan los framework de php ... cuando comienzas a personalizar cosas comienza todo a convulcionar ...

Comment: Si funciona, y solo tendría que cambiar en mi bd la columna password_user por password, pero igual quería pedir ayuda por si alguien conocía una manera de hacerlo sin cambiar eso

Comment: el tema es que si no existiera algo deberia de darte un error de php todo grotesco y no dejarte sin saber que esta pasando en el backend...

Comment: la funcionalida principal de trabajar con un framework es para hacer las cosas dentro de ese estandar o marco de trabajo, cuando comienzas a alterar cosas, los script dejan de funcionar... si debe haber alguna otra forma de hacer la sesion sin apterar la columna pero puede que necesites otras librerias o hacer cogido nativo.

Comment: Fijate si te sirve sobreescribir esta función en el modelo https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/44562